# All my desktop file icons have a small symbol; where is it coming from?

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, icons, desktop-icons

As of a few days ago, all of my files on the desktop have a small icon on them - see the first image in the bottom.

- Why is that extra symbol being added?
- If a program is adding the icon, how can I find out which program is doing it?

My recently-installed programs list doesn't have anything seemingly relevant - see the second image in the bottom.
Docker could possibly be the source of it, but it's been changed already a week ago and I don't think that this has been happening for so long.

[Deleting the Icon Cache](https://superuser.com/questions/971215/why-do-all-my-desktop-icons-all-have-a-red-x-in-the-lower-left) didn't help.

Running the [System File Checker](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/desktop-icons-have-symbols-on-them/ac95c7f6-e9a4-4c68-8eb7-75f31121dd4f) didn't help either.

---

## The icons

[image: an image showing the extra symbol on all the icons]

## List of recently installed/updated programs

[image: a list showing the recently updated programs]

Comment: The arrows suggest to me upload/download, e.g., sync with cloud/backup - did you recently start doing such sync or backup?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin No, I did not. The duplicate question answers why they are being shown. But not why they started being shown... :( I didn't turn compression on.

Comment: *"But not why they started being shown..."*  If your system is running relatively low on disk space and it installed Windows updates recently, that is probably why they started being shown:  [This update may compress files in your user profile directory to help free up enough disk space to install important updates.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023057/update-to-windows-10-versions-1507-1511-1607-1703-1709-and-1803-for-up)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the arrows mean the files are being compressed. If you turn off compression in Properties > General > Advanced, do they go away?

Comment: Yes. Thank you, the duplicate question is the correct answer. Now I just need to figure out why everything started being compressed...